# VSCode run formatter on save without needing to save twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code

I have a command that runs on save and formats the file, obviously then the file changes and needs to be saved again. Is there a way to make it so I don't need to hit save twice?

```
"runItOn": {
     "commands": [
       {
         "match": ".rb",
         "isShellCommand": false,
         "cmd": "extension.rubyReplace"
       }
     ]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter shortcut keys"ctrl+shift+P",open the file "setting.json",
add the following lines to this file:
"editor.formatOnType": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
This will format the code on save.